# How to send JSON string from arduino to android device in terms of response and then decode the string on the android application?

Tags: android, json, arduino

I am currently working on a project whereby i need to send a request from an android application to my Arduino mega which in turns response back with the states of LEDs connnected to the Arduino. I have already implemented the GET request. However i need to know how to read the response back and how to send the string from the Arduino to the Android app.

Here is the code for the response:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
client.println("{\"status\":\"ok\"}"); // <--- how to create the string?
```

and also how to decode it from the android application. I have seen tutorials on the internet about using InputStream to do so but am unable to understand the code. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Would recommend using `Retrofit` (and `gson`) for something like this.

Comment: I have never used retrofit. I have already written the cod in an Async task class. The issue is that how can i read send the string from the arduino and then how i read the response back in the doInBackground method in the Async Task

Comment: As the Arduino is usually very restricted I recommend not to use HTTP if you only want to send one string. A simple string can be send directly via socket.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a Webserver on Arduino side and use a HTTP library (i.e. OkHTTTP) to connect to the Webserver.
I used OkHTTP on Android side but you could use other libraries too.
This [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/03/arduino-led-control-android-app.html) is something like you are looking for. It is from my blog.

Otherwise you can use aRest. It is very simple to use. If you want to know more give a look at this [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/05/arduino-rest-api-iot.html) from my blog.